How to get the embed link for the PowerBI report created through the SharePoint Online's Integration feature?
For context, in an SPO list, there's a cool feature where you can quickly spin up a PowerBI report by going to Integrate > PowerBI > Visualize this list.

I get that by publishing the report to the list, others can access that same report. However, how how do you get the embed URL to display on another SP page? Similarly to how you can embed your own pbix file (assuming it's published to your PowerBI workspace). Is this even possible?
Google has been unkind in returning results since the terms are so generic - I only see results for tutorials on how to do the embed itself or how to create the PowerBI
TIA
